# Rails: tools for auto-building existing project features/structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, structure

I need to create new version of my current project - take all features and rewrite it, add new features.

What tools or gems do we have for Rails project to build for me some kind of catalogue of existing features? Maybe in form of models and associations between it or some kind of graphs.
 After it I will be able to customize such information for my needs. Anyway it should be simpler than go through all code and make it from scratch by myself.

All help appreciated.

Comment: if you adding -1, then it would be better to disclose the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found such gem for my case:
https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd

It's not totally what I was seeking for, but still useful.